# Arithmetic Sequences Problems

Tags: arithmetic

Find the sum $S$ defined by
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{20} \left(3n-\frac{ 1}{2}\right).$$

I have

$$S = 3 \sum_{n=1}^{20} n- \sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac{ 1}{2} = 3(210) - 10 = 620,$$

but the answer is supposed to be 1380?

Comment: I have edited the first equation; can you learn from my example and edit the rest so it is more readable?

Comment: sorry, i am not good at using technology:)

Comment: using your formula, the answer is 620.

Comment: @user184563, you better try lest not many people will even try to read your question.

Comment: @user184563 did I edit your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is $S=620$.

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^{20}\Big(3n-\frac12\Big) \\
&=3\sum_{n=1}^{20}n-\sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac12 \\
&=3\frac{20\cdot21}{2}-20\cdot\frac12 \\
&=3\cdot210-10 \\
&=\boxed{620}
\end{align}$$